# Убрать анимацию при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Всем привет.

У меня есть анимация сделанная с помощью `@keyframes` и есть `hover-эффект` при наведении.

Так вот мне нужно чтобы анимация сделанная с помощью `@keyframes` исчезла при наведении.

Заранее прошу прошение за такой длинный код, просто хотел чтобы он корректно отображался.
Мне говорили, что это можно сделать с помощью `JS`, но я не особо в нем разбираюсь.

Кому не сложно, помогите пожалуйста.

```css
body {
  background: #3a3939;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #7d8a96;
}

#surname,
#name,
#patronymic {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #2196f3;
  background: #3a3939;
  color: #c9cdd0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.selected {
  text-align: center;
  color: #83c0f6
}

#select {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  background: #3a3939;
  color: #83c0f6;
  border: 1px solid #2196f3;
}

#comment {
  background: #3a3939;
  color: #c9cdd0;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #2196f3;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#comment::placeholder {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.blick {
  position: absolute;
  background: #b2d8fa;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 2.5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 89%;
  transform: translateX(-4em) skewX(-45deg);
  animation: btn-blick 2.5s infinite 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes btn-blick {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-4em) skewX(-45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(20em) skewX(-45deg);
  }
}

.btn-decor {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #83c0f6;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 94px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;*/
}

.btn-line {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.btn-line-top {
  top: 0px;
  left: -100%;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}

.btn-line-right {
  right: 0px;
  top: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}

.btn-line-bottom {
  bottom: 0px;
  right: -100%;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}

.btn-line-left {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}

#btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #83c0f6;
  background: #3a3939;
  border: 2px solid #2196f3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

#btn:hover {
  border: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  background: #2196f3;
  color: #3a3939;
  /*background: linear-gradient(45deg, #83c0f6, #C5DDE8)*/
  ;
}

.btn-decor:hover .btn-line-top {
  left: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.btn-decor:hover .btn-line-right {
  top: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.18s;
}

.btn-decor:hover .btn-line-bottom {
  right: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.btn-decor:hover .btn-line-left {
  bottom: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-delay: 0.18s;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Фамилия" id="surname" title="Введите вашу фамилию">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" id="name" title="Введите ваше имя">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Отчество" id="patronymic" title="Введите ваше отчество">
  </p>
  <p class="selected">
    <label for="select">Укажите возраст</label> <br>
    <select name="select" id="select">
      <option disabled selected>Ваш возраст</option>
      <option value="sm-16">До 16</option>
      <option value="16-21">16-21</option>
      <option value="21-27">21-27</option>
      <option value="27-35">27-35</option>
      <option value="35-45">35-45</option>
      <option value="45-55">45-55</option>
      <option value="up-55">Больше 55</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="42" rows="8" placeholder="Введите информацию о себе"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p class="btn-decor" id="btn-decor">
    <span class="blick" id="blick"></span>
    <span class="btn-line btn-line-top"></span>
    <span class="btn-line btn-line-right"></span>
    <span class="btn-line btn-line-bottom"></span>
    <span class="btn-line btn-line-left"></span>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Отправить">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js не нужен, попробуйте добавить:

```
.btn-decor:hover .blick {
    animation: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли. Ваш вариант сработал!